# SRAP marker sequences

Tags: pcr

I am looking into SRAP markers and I have realized I am not sure if I need a reverse complement of the sequence given in the article or they are "ready to use" primers?

Comment: Can you add sources or links to your markers and explain what you are planning to do so that users can provide you with more accurate answers?

Comment: Which article are you talking about?